# Laravel select old and new value as selected

Tags: laravel, foreach, html-select, selected, laravel-8

Not sure exactly how to ask this question. But how do you select the old value after you fetched the value from the database? When you click on edit, you fetch the database result. But if something goes wrong, I want the value selected that the user inserted.

This is what works if you want to add a value.

```php
<select name="category_id" class="form-control" id="category">
    @foreach($category as $cat)
        <option value="{{$cat->id}}"
            {{ old('category_id', $cat->id) == $subCategory->category_id ? "selected" : "" }}>
            {{ $cat->category_en }} | {{ $cat->category_de }}</option>
    @endforeach
</select>
```

However, when I press update, it doesn't use the old selected value, but it automatically goes to the first option in the foreach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use [optional()](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/helpers#method-optional) helper along with the [old()](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/helpers#method-old) helper to handle this kind of situation.

```
<option value="{{ $cat->id }}" @if (old('category_id', optional($subCategory)->category_id) == $cat->id) selected @endif>{{ $cat->category_en }} | {{ $cat->category_de }}</option>
```

what this means is when it gets old input value null, it will use the object value to select an item. when there is old input value it will select the old input value. you can omit the optional helper though, it is useful when you are using the same form for create and update.

Comment: Doesnt seem to work :(, tried to directly copy what you said, and tried to add optional in my own line of code, both didnt do it

Comment: `$subCategory->category_id` does this have any matching value with category??

Comment: lets say the subcategory->categoy_id = 4, it fetches the value when i go to the edit screen correctly. Cause in the foreach it will find the 4 == 4, but once you press on update, it uses the old subcategory->category_id, instead of the just filled in category_id

Comment: you have swapped the variables here and i have completely missed that. updating my answer.

Comment: Sometimes such small mistakes are overseen for days...Thank you my friend, thank you a lot!

Answer (score 0):

```
<select name="category_id" class="form-control" id="category">
     @foreach($category as $cat)
     <option value="{{$cat->id}}" 
  @if($cat->id == $subCategory->category_id) ? selected : '' @endif>
   {{ $cat->category_en }} | {{ $cat->category_de }}</option>
     @endforeach
     </select>
```